# Как из цифры сделать массив?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть цифра `const x = 5`
Как мне из нее получить массив [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

Такая возможность есть у лодаш `_.range(1, 5+1)` но я хочу сделать это не используя библиотеки.
Можно использовать цикл, но не могу понять как это реализовать. Подскажите.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> У меня есть цифра const x = 5 Как мне из нее получить массив [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]?

Например так...

```js
const x = 5
const arr = Array.from({length: x}, (_, i) => ++i)
console.log(arr)
```

Можно еще вот так...

```js
const x = 5
const arr = Array(x).fill(0).map((_, i) => ++i)
console.log(arr)
```

Навеяло вариантом из комментария... :)

```js
const x = 5
const arr = Array.from(' '.repeat(x), (_, i) => ++i)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @user20389696, если ответ вам помог, отметьте его верным нажав на серую галочку

Comment: `Array.from(Array(5).keys(), i => i + 1)`. В процессе работы не создаются дополнительные массивы линейного размера. Как и в вашем первом примере.

Answer (score 1):

Если прям максимально просто, тогда вот такой вариант:

```
const x = 5;
const arr = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
}

console.log(arr);
```